# I want to alternate shading of table rows in HTML but only apply it to ONE of multiple tables

Tags: html, css

The following code works well if you want to have the same alternate row shading for all tables on the page:

```
<style>
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}

th, td {
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}
</style>
```

But I only want one of my tables to have this alternate shading.  I thought I could just replace the name "table" with ".floatedTable" to apply the shading to the tables with class='floatedTable' but it doesn't do anything.

The way I'd prefer to do it is just find something to write inside of

Comment: In a real production environment you would do this by making 2 classes.  1 shaded, 1 normal and then apply them as needed.  `nth-child` can get confusing and is sometimes hard to debug.

Comment: `nth-child(even)` is not really confusing, unless you start adding numbers and calculations, but `even` is pretty straightforward.

Comment: I'm going to have to respectfully disagree.  In a production environment `pseudo classes` like `:last-child`, `:nth-child(n)` etc. are generally frowned upon and discouraged.  Vanilla classes are much easier to debug particularly when you are working on someone elses code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the style to apply only to a certain table by class, you should nest the TH in that class definition:

```
<style>
    .floatedTable{
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .floatedTable th, .floatedTable td {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    .floatedTable tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
</style>
```

When you start learning SCSS, you'll do it like this:

```
.floatedTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }
  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Phiter beat me to it, but here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/targumon/y8z6hgxn/2/

```
.floatedTable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #d08080;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

For row shading, you can use the bootstrap class "table-striped" in the HTML.

The class will only be active on the table element it is contained in.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
 <tr>
  <th>Meals</th>
  <th>Prices</th>
  <th>Drinks</th>
  <th>Prices</th>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td>Macaroni and Cheese</td>
  <td>£3.59</td>
  <td>Coca Cola</td>
  <td>£1.15</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you please accept my answer as the accepted answer @MelerLawler

Comment: How do I do that? EDIT:  Oh I got it

Comment: So... I guess you are using bootstrap? This answer is kind of out of nowhere, but accepted...